# Please help me with Error in Spring Boot 2,

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-boot

I have a procedure stored in sql server 2014:

```
create database db_spring_2
use db_spring_2
create table tb_usuario( id_usuario int primary key identity(1,1), nombre varchar(200), apellidopat varchar(200), apellidomat varchar(200), email varchar(200) unique, foto_url varchar(500) )
insert into tb_usuario values('Marcos','Marcos','MAr','mar@gmail.com', '123.jpg')

go alter proc usp_usuario as begin select nombre from tb_usuario end
```

I'm calling from in a Spring boot 2 project but I get this error:

```js
019-08-21 19:51:31.284 ERROR 6752 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The column name id_usuario is not valid.
2019-08-21 19:51:31.292 ERROR 6752 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query] with root cause

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name id_usuario is not valid.
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:206) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar:na]
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.findColumn(SQLServerResultSet.java:686) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar:na]
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getInt(SQLServerResultSet.java:2337) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar:na]
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getInt(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
 at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
 at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
 at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
 at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
 at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
 at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
 at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:793) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
```

Here the method where you called the stored procedure

```js
package com.example.demo.repository;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.demo.entity.Usuarios;

@Repository
public interface IUsuarioRepository extends CrudRepository<Usuarios, Integer>{

 @Query(value = "exec usp_usuario" , nativeQuery=true )
 public List<Usuarios> getUsuarios();
}
```

My Service interface

```js
package com.example.demo.repository;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.demo.entity.Usuarios;

public interface IUsuarioService {

 public List<Usuarios> getUsuarios();
}
```

And my service

```js
package com.example.demo.services;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.demo.entity.Usuarios;
import com.example.demo.repository.IUsuarioRepository;
import com.example.demo.repository.IUsuarioService;

@Transactional
@Service
public class UusuarioServices implements IUsuarioService {

 @Autowired
 private IUsuarioRepository usuarioR;
 
 @Override
 public List<Usuarios> getUsuarios() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return usuarioR.getUsuarios();
 }

}
```

My Controller Rest

```js
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/usuario")
public class UsuarioController {
 
 @Autowired
 private IUsuarioService usuarioS;
 
 @GetMapping("/listadoUsuario")
 public List<Usuarios> getUsuario(){
  return usuarioS.getUsuarios();
 }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your com.example.demo.entity.Usuarios class?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `IUsuarioRepository` is attempting to populate the entire `Usuarios` entity but your query returned only the `nombre` field.

You haven't shown all the relevant code, i.e. the definition of `Usuarios`, but the query should probably be `select *...` not `select nombre...`  The current query returns only the single `nombre` column, while the framework is expecting the returned result set to contain (at a minimum) the `id_usuario` column as well.

Comment: and how do I solve that when you want certain columns in the stored procedure

Comment: It's not clear why you want to use a stored procedure at that point.  If you are populating an entity, then the stored procedure needs to return all the columns required by that entity, and usually all you need is a simple query for that.  The key point is that the query must return all the data required by the entity being populated.  That is fundamental.